# Can I delete files which were added but not committed to git?

Tags: git

Git seems to retain blobs which were added but not committed

```
#> mkdir foo
#> cd foo
#> echo a > data.txt
#> git add data.txt
#> find .git/objects
.git/objects/58/7be6b4c3f93f93c489c0111bba5596147a26cb
```

Okay now change the contents.

```
#> echo b > data.txt
#> git add data.txt
#> find .git/objects
.git/objects/61/780798228d17af2d34fce4cfbdf35556832472
.git/objects/58/7be6b4c3f93f93c489c0111bba5596147a26cb
```

We don't need `58/7be6b4c3f93f93c489c0111bba5596147a26cb` anymore, do we?

```
#> git commit -m 'first'
#> find ./git/objects
.git/objects/c0/eef182819e5c530c407ca17a24e39cb6682ed3
.git/objects/61/780798228d17af2d34fce4cfbdf35556832472
.git/objects/58/7be6b4c3f93f93c489c0111bba5596147a26cb
.git/objects/70/a6a81a455bea58166d60d21060b074d3271b6a
```

The orphan `58/7be6b4c3f93f93c489c0111bba5596147a26cb` is still there.

I've done `git add` on a lot of files which then changed before they were committed. Can I remove the blobs which are no longer referenced by the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any reason why you couldn't, and git seems to agree:
Running `git fsck --unreachable` shows it as dangling node,
`git prune --dry-run` shows it would be removed.

I would not run it by hand though (in a normal repo/work scenario) - `git gc` command has exactly this purpose: (from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

> Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository,
>   such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase
>   performance) and removing unreachable objects which may have been
>   created from prior invocations of git add.
>
> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each
>   repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating
>   performance.